# Cpanel cron jobs not working using magento?

Tags: php, magento, cron, cpanel, magento-1.8

**Anyone please help me**

Domain: Godaddy

Hosting: VPS server

Name Server: MNS01.DOMAINCONTROL.COM

Name Server: MNS02.DOMAINCONTROL.COM

---

Below are test case scenarios i did and got the result

For cron.php file gave permission to 777

Minutes Hour Day Month Weekday  set  to  * * * * *

**Test 1:**

/home/domain/public_html/cron.php

```
Result:

/home/domain/public_html/cron.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/home/domain/public_html/cron.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `dirname'
/home/domain/public_html/cron.php: line 2: `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));'
```

**Test 2:**

/usr/bin/php -q  /home/domain/public_html/cron.php

```
Result:

Nothing display
```

**Test 3:**

php -q  /home/domain/public_html/cron.php

```
Result:

Nothing display
```

**Test 4:**

/usr/bin/php  /home/domain/public_html/cron.php

```
Result:

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.33
Content-type: text/html
```

**Test 5:**

GET https://www.domain.com/cron.php

```
Result:

LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module
is installed.
```

**Test 6:**

GET http://www.domain.com/cron.php

```
Result:

Nothing display
```

**Test 7:**

I replaced above all test cron.php replaced to cron.sh and tested. Got same result.

**Test 8:**

/home/domain/public_html/test.php

```
code:

<?php echo "hello world";?>

Result:

/home/domain/public_html/cron.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
hello world
```

Comment: It's normal for nothing to display when cron.php runs. Via command line, you just get a new command prompt, via http, all you get back is an http header and a blank page. The only way you can tell it's working because you end up with entries in the `cron_schedule` table. At which point, I'd use phpMyAdmin to check for entries from all the times you got those blank results and concentrate on the ones where you got error messages.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177502/magento-cron-job/25183755. There are some suggestions. I found that for my provider 1and1 I had to specify the right version of php (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got result..

```
php -q /home/username/public_html/cron.php
```

or

`php -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php`

or

`php-cli -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php`

**Reference:**

> http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-do-i-put-for-the-cron-job-command

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get any of the above suggestions to work, but did arrive at my own solution.

I had a Magento site on a dedicated server which I moved to a Cpanel shared web host (VentraIP) - and could not get the cron working. I was seeing "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME" and "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME" errors in the error_log. I ended up modifying the cron.php (renamed to cron_for_cpanel.php) to be as follows:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

try {    
    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');

    Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('default');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}
```

The cron in Cpanel was then:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/cron_for_cpanel.php
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I was having the same issue with running the Magento cronjob on VentraIP and this rectified my issue.

Answer (score 0):

if your website was working, try to recompile Apache and PHP with EasyApache.

If recompile doesn't work, you can try update LWP manually (thinking in this error: LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module is installed.)

```
wget http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/cpan/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/libwww-perl-5.812.tar.gz   
tar xzf libwww-perl-5.812.tar.gz
cd libwww-perl-5.812
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

New/Best update code:

```
rpm -qi perl-libwww-perl
/scripts/realperlinstaller --force LWP
```

Comment: Thanks let me try, Actually test 8 works but whyt this error ?php: No such file or directory

Comment: Im not able to install above code in cpanel shell command. No response from server.

Comment: Link updated. New update code added, hope help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `cron.sh` file over command line (not a `GET`), and specify the `sh` path

```
/bin/sh /home/domain/public_html/cron.sh
```

Comment: This return Test 4 result. Do you have any idea on this?