# Magento error when running Cron.php

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I am getting this error when I run the cron.php for Magento.
[24-Jan-2015 02:40:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage__Helper_Data' not found in /home/nli/catalog/app/Mage.php on line 516

I found a few other pages where someone else had this problem but I am unable to fix this. The two underscores must be the issue but I cannot find anywhere in my Magento directories with grep where there is any mention of Mage__Helper_Data or anything calling that class.

Please let me know if you have any ideas on what I could check. This has been happening for at least a couple months so I have no idea what happened or which plugins were installed at the exact time.
Thank you!

-Justin

Comment: Have you seen this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177502/magento-cron-job/25183755#25183755. There might be something relevant there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A magento developer was able to take a look at our system and found the issue was within a 3rd party magento plugin that had a corrupt row in the database table that was causing the Mage__Helper_Data error.

Answer (score 0):

This should be in one of the *config.xml* files in your system; it seems like one word is missing between *Mage_* and *_Helper*; btw what is the grep command you are using? try with: `grep "Mage__Helper" . -rin` , from the top folder. I'm sure you'll find something.