# Magento cron job not working

Tags: php, magento, cron

I have configured cron job in my admin's custom module in magento but cron job is not working.Nothing in my **magento->var->log->system log file**.below is my full module details:.

JR->CreateAdminController->etc->config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <JR_CreateAdminController>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </JR_CreateAdminController>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <jr_createadmincontroller>
            <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
            <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>
        </jr_createadmincontroller>
    </helpers>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <jr_createadmincontroller before="Mage_Adminhtml">JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml</jr_createadmincontroller>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
<layout>
    <updates>
  <petra>
      <file>createadmincontroller.xml</file>
     </petra>
 </updates>   
</layout>
</adminhtml>
<!-- ++++++++++++CRON JOB CODE++++++++++++ -->
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <jr_createadmincontroller>
            <schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>createadmincontroller/observer::setStatus</model></run>
        </jr_createadmincontroller>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
</config>
```

JR->CreateAdminController->Model->Observer.php

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Model_Observer {
public function setStatus() {
    echo "let see!!!";
    Mage::log("WORKS!");
 }
 }
?>
```

Why Mage::log not write any thing in my log file and also how will i check my cron is running or not. pLease help me out !!!!

Comment: REASON TO DOWN VOTE THIS QUESTION ?

Comment: cron is configured correctly on the server and cron.conf includes the magento cron.sh or cron.php ?

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf no how can i do? according to my scenario?? thanks in advanced

Comment: It depends on your server. Additionnaly, my knowledge is not really good on that side. If you need to try anyway you can launch, cron.php in your browser.

Comment: You've not mentioned whether you've confirmed the Magento cron itself is actually running or not.  I'd advise you install AEO_Scheduler, make sure there's a heartbeat and then run your job directly from the scheduler to check it. https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

Comment: Loads of setup info on the magento cron http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob

Comment: Might be something useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177502/magento-cron-job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't declare your models in your config.xml but observer is a model.
You should add

```
<models>
        <jr_createadmincontroller>
            <class>JR_CreateAdminController_Model</class>
        </jr_createadmincontroller>
    </models>
```

In the global node.
And change this

```
<run><model>createadmincontroller/observer::setStatus</model></run>
```

By this:

```
<run><model>jr_createadmincontroller/observer::setStatus</model></run>
```

Comment: hey!! i tried with your answer.but still i'm not getting anything in my system.log (magento->var->log->system log) file.please check what else we need to add.

Comment: also it will run directly or need to create any cron.php file

Comment: Il will run with cron.php but, does your server have a cronjob on cron.php ?

Comment: in my magento folder there is one cron.php file.when i run that file i get "let see!!!"; in my browser as it is written in my observer.php

Comment: And be sure that your cron.php gets executed by your server every minuts

Comment: can you tell me how i make my server to execute my cron.php in every minute ? i am using wamp (localhost) in windows

Comment: Well this is another subject, but basically, in your shell:

crontab -e

Add line:

*     *       *       *       *       php /your/complete/path/to/cron.php

Some will tell you to use cron.sh, but i don't know the difference and it works well this way.

Comment: And i give +1 to the comment that suggests you to install AOE_Scheduler http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

Comment: thanks for you post.i upvoted & accepted your answer :)

Comment: every thing is working perfectly but only Mage::log not write any thing in my log file(magento->var->log->system log file)

Comment: 1. Check that the logs are enabled in System -> Config -> Developer. 2. Check that the log files are writable for your server

Comment: :thankz.now it's working :) (System -> Config -> Developer) this works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71166/discussion-between-priyank-and-jonapkr).