# Magento cron job not running

Tags: php, xml, magento, cron

I have the following code within the config.xml file of a Magento module. I've tried the cron expression in various formats, but whatever i do I can't get Magento to set up a cron job based on this config. I've run cron.sh and cron.php - can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

EDIT: this is different from the other question mentioned, in that I have declared my models correctly so that isn't the issue

```
 <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <base_polyvorefeed_export>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>base_polyvorefeed/observer::exportProductFeed</model>
            </run>
        </base_polyvorefeed_export>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento cron job not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538342/magento-cron-job-not-working)

Comment: i've been through the process described in that question but it doesn't seem to have worked

Comment: You could try looking into AOE_Scheduler to help with cron scheduling and debugging.

Comment: There might be something useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177502/magento-cron-job/25183755

Comment: @JamieMaxwell what did you tried that make you so positive about your model being correctly configured ? Did you try to lunch `http://your-magento-url/cron.php` ? Do you have any `base_polyvorefeed_export` `job_code` in the table `cron_schedule` of your database ?

Comment: an easy way to check if configuration worked (don't forget to clear cache!) is to list cron jobs with magerun: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun (it also clears the cache for you if you want to)

Comment: thanks all. i've done some more tests on this and records are being added to cron_schedule table in my development environment, the issue seems to be when it's deployed to the live environment, so i think this is an internal issue with our system. appreciate your input anyways.