# Magento 1.9.1 Cron Not Running

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento-1.9.1

I am having big issues with the cron of Magento 1.9.1 hoping someone can help. I have AOE installed and see not heartbeat.

I have added my cron job

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /var/sites/p/domain/public_html/cron.sh
```

But this still does not run, so I decided to try and try and run cron.php, this does nothing. This is my cron for this

```
*/5 * * * */usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://www.domain.com/cron.php
```

Based on Magneto 1.8 cron.php I added the following to the cron.php.

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

Based on this still not working I tried the cron.php in the browser. I get an error in the browser that Printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

So I changed my php.ini to memory_limit = 512M just incase. This is still not working.

The error I get in my reports for this is:

```
 a:5:{i:0;s:59:"Mage registry key "_singleton/cron/observer" already exists";i:1;s:537:"#0 /var/sites/p/domain.co.uk/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/sites/p/domain.co.uk/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/cron...', false)
#2 /var/sites/p/domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('cron/observer')
#3 /var/sites/p/domain.co.uk/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#4 /var/sites/p/domain.co.uk/public_html/cron.php(74): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#5 {main}";s:3:"url";s:9:"/cron.php";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Any help would be really great.

Note ** I have change the domain name to DOMAIN due to my site not being suitable for work.

Comment: When you go to AOE's list view (System >> Scheduler >> List View), do you see any jobs listed? If not, click the 'Generate Schedule' button at the top. Do you see jobs listed now?

Comment: There might be some suggestions in here that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177502/magento-cron-job/25183755

Comment: Are crons running at all on the server ? What's happening when you launch  php cron.php at the root of the magento's folder ?

Answer (score 18):

Few simple steps to fix Magento cron issue:

1. Go to System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks) and set next values:

   - Generate Schedules Every: 15
   - Schedule Ahead for: 20
   - Missed if Not Run Within: 15
   - History Cleanup Every: 10
   - Success History Lifetime: 60
   - Failure History Lifetime: 600
2. Clear Cache in System > Cache Management
3. Clear 'cron_schedule' table. You can do it via phpmyadmin or execute next command in SQL console:

   TRUNCATE TABLE cron_schedule;
4. Add next line to cron settings (use absolute paths):

   */5 * * * *  /usr/bin/php /absolute/path/on/your/server/to/file/cron.php

Note: in some configurations on webserver (apache/nginx) allowed to execute php scripts. In this case add this line to webserver's user crontab. Example for apache: crontab -u apache -e

5. Restart cron daemon.
6. Check table 'cron_schedule', if it's not empty - Magento cron script start working.

Comment: where to write "*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sites/p/domain/public_html/cron.php"

Comment: It depends of your system. In Linux OS in most common case type "crontab -e" and add this line.

Comment: This didn't exactly work for me, But it was close: 
Follow Steps 1 2 3 4 
Then step 5 should be: 
*/5 * * * * apache /var/www/dev/company_dev/cron.sh
Then step 5 and 6 is fine.  

The cron.sh script calls the php file and Apache is the only user who has permissions to alter and run scripts in Magento. Thus the change in executor.

Comment: @dustbuster - here is thousand ways for setup web server, I provide working instruction for topic starter's variant. In your case if apache have access to cron (pam settings) you can do step 4 via command: crontab -u apache -e

Comment: Absolutely. I wasn't suggesting there was anything wrong with your answer. Just wanted to provide some additional info in case someone runs into the same issues I did!

Comment: How to restart cron deamon?!

Answer (score 9):

Well I've had a different issue. My cron was simply not working, although cron.php was executed properly. Still no output, and no jobs done.

I've checked cron_schedule and noticed that last job there is from 19th of March this year (sic!). So i kept on looking for cause.

Finally I've noticed that that there is process running with my cronjob from 19th of March (sic!).

`josh    21350 99.6  0.4 350400 133492 ?       R    Mar19 241812:21 /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/cron.php -mdefault`

I've killed the job with: `kill -9 21350`

And voila! Suddenly newsletter is being sent!

I had no idea why, and how this happened. Now i know i should pay attention to it, so I will.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that you are using magento 1.9.1.

Run the cron using php instead :  /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/cpanel_username/public_html/cron.php

This should resolve http permission problems you might be having when using 'usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null'

Try that command and let me know if it works for you.